# push value after nested Iteration finished in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested-loops

I have a nested for loop which iterates over each nested array and does a calculation with it and an other array ---> stores the result

I added a counter to check when the inner iteration is finished

the dataset is goingt to be very large so I want to exclude for performance es many extra steps as possible
how can I achive the same result without the counter ?

```
const zip = (a,b) => a.map((x,i) => [x,b[i]]);
// for a, b in zip(list1, list2):
const firstArray = [[1,2], [2,1]];

const secondArray = [4,5]

const container = [];

for (const nestedArray of firstArray) {
    
    let counter = 0;
    let sum = 0;
    for (const [a,b] of zip(nestedArray, secondArray )) {
        let x = a *b;
        sum += x
        counter ++

        if (counter === nestedArray.length) {
            container.push(sum)
        }
       
        
       
    }
}
```

Comment: by pushing after the inner loop but still inside the outer loop

Comment: In other words, the `push(sum)` line should be on the same indent level as `sum=0` line.

Comment: And if you're concerned about performance, your `zip` is what is killing it.